# Unable to query a view created using sdo_nn statment

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, spatial

```
CREATE VIEW bd_nearest_hy AS         
SELECT b1.b_name, h1.h_id
FROM   building b1,hydrant h1 
WHERE  sdo_nn(h1.shape, b1.shape,'sdo_num_res = 1') = 'TRUE';

SELECT  bd_nearest_hy.b_name
FROM    bd_nearest_hy
WHERE   bd_nearest_hy.h_id = 'p30';
```

I created a view, which is used to store the building name and its corresponding nearest hydrant. The sdo_nn statement works fine and the view is correct.

However, when I select the row contains `h_id = p30` from the view, the database says:
Error report:

```
SQL Error: ORA-13249: SDO_NN cannot be evaluated without using index
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MD", line 1723
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.MDERR", line 17 
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.PRVT_IDX", line 9
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: Read the suggestions in this article: http://www.spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks/73/using-oracles-sdonn-operator-some-examples